# Como conseguir que una columna de un grid al reducir el campo en vez de dejar de ver la parte derecha de este dejar de ver la parte izquierda

Tags: c#, html5, webforms

En el grid el campo Plantilla
Actualmente para ver el nombre de la plantilla entera tienes que hacer el campo largo hasta que entre el nombre para poder ver el final del nombre de la plantilla. El final del nombre de la plantilla es lo que diferencia la plantilla del resto de plantillas de la ruta
[image: Imagen de lo que ocurre campo plantilla]

al reducir el campo en vez de dejar de ver la parte derecha de este dejar de ver la parte izquierda.
[image: Imagen con lo que se necesita]

Que propiedad debo añadir para obtener el resultado de la segunda imagen ?

El código actual es el siguiente

```
column = grid.RootTable.Columns.Add();
        column.AllowRemove = InheritableBoolean.True;
        column.Caption = "Plantilla";
        column.EditType = EditType.TextBox;
        column.DataMember = "ShortName";
        column.Key = column.DataMember;
        column.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        column.Visible = false;
        column.Width = 100;
        column.ButtonStyle = ButtonStyle.ButtonCell;
        column.HeaderToolTip = "Plantilla asociada a una regla que actúa en ese vuelo/fecha";
        column.CellToolTip = CellToolTip.NoToolTip;
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Procura dar el máximo de información posible en tus preguntas para que la gente pueda ayudarte. Entiendo que estás haciendo una aplicación ASP.NET con WebForms y estás utilizando algún control tipo Grid. ¿Puede ser de DevExpress? Esta información es importante para que quien quiera ayudarte pueda situarse.

Comment: Ok!! el control de grid es bajo Janus

Comment: Entiendo que establecer el `TextAlignment` a `Right` no es una opción.

Comment: exacto , no es una opción

Answer (score 0):

Con css puedes hacerlo metiendo el contenido en un `div` con un ancho mínimo del 100% de la celda y alineado a la derecha (`float: right`) para que cuando crezca porque el contenido no cabe crezca hacia la izquierda.

Mira este ejemplo. Según vas escribiendo texto en el `input` se va actualizando el contenido de la celda. Cuando no cabe el `div` crece hacia la izquierda con lo que el contenido que queda oculto es el del principio.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#input').keyup(function(){
    $('#content').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```css
td{
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td div{
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  max-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="content"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="input" type="text" />
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta , pero no es eso lo que quiero decir quizás me he explicado mal , lo único que intento hacer es que cuando minimizo la columna de plantilla su información no se oculte por la derecha sino por la izquierda pero no encuentro la propiedad que trata eso

Comment: Por lo que he visto el GridEx de Janus no tiene posibilidad de establecer ese tipo de visualización (o al menos no lo he encontrado). Por eso te proponía hacerlo manipulando los estilos de la celda directamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias , lo haré de ese modo